# OpenJDK 8 Lambdas processing

Tags: java, lambda, jvm

In my current project I want to be able to "reinstantiate" a lambda method (don't know if "reinstantiate" is the right word though)

Consider a following example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    TestUser tu = new TestUser();

    ITest1 lam = t->{
        System.out.println("whoops" + tu.toString());
        return 1;
    };

    tu.doExec(lam);

    calls++;
    if( calls == 1) main(args);
}
```

Here I ve tried to debug through the JVM calls and I noticed that JVM creates and `MethodType` and `MethodHandle` objects for the metafactory method (which creates builds `CallSite`) and for my lambda method. Now once this is done `linkCallSite` is invoked. This method builds the CallSite and links the lambda method to it just once. At this point, my question is, can I somehow delete the lambda CallSite and LambdaForm from the jvm and somehow trigger the whole process again?

And another question, when debugging through the JVM calls i noticed that every time when JVM executes the lambda method, a method `Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaForm$MH/818403870;.linkToTargetMethod(Object)` gets invoked, which i cannot find sourcecode of, neither in JVM cpp sources, nor in java. How exactly is this method called, or where does it get invoked?

I know the question is kind of complicated, so I am open to your questions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with "reinstantiate" ??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I want to delete the LamdaForms and CallSite from the jvm so that jvm would have to do the whole instantiation procedure again...

Comment: have you tried loading the class in question under a different classloader?

Comment: @the8472 Hey, I did not try that as i do not see a way of unloading a class and reloading it... The child classloader would always provide me a class loaded by its parrents... What exactly do you mean though? Imagine if my class which contains a lambda function, has different states, wouldnt i lose the current state by unloading and reloading it back? What exactly would i need to reload and how would a child classloader look like?

Comment: BTW, why do you want to redo linking process?

Comment: @apangin I'm working on a lil fun project, me and a friend are trying to make different executions of a program to behave deterministic. While a lot of things work already, `invokedynamic` is a problem because it might have been linked to the CallSite already when we start the tracing in the first run. Since in the second run it is not linked yet the JVM will invoke the corresponding methods, leading to events that we did not trace in the first run. Would be great if we could chat a little more about that...

Answer (score 1):

> can I somehow delete the lambda CallSite and LambdaForm from the jvm
>   and somehow trigger the whole process again?

`invokedynamic` is linked to a CallSite (or sometimes directly to the target method) just once at the bytecode resolution time. The resolution result is saved in the constant pool cache and is not modified afterwards.

One possible way to reset the constant pool cache is to redefine the class. I don't count reloading the class in a different ClassLoader, since this is technically the same as loading a new class not related to an old one.

So, in order to trigger `linkCallSite` stuff once again, you may call [Instrumentation.redefineClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses-java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...-) or the equivalent JVM TI [RedefineClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#RedefineClasses) function.

> How exactly is this method called, or where does it get invoked?

`linkToTargetMethod` is an adapter created dynamically in runtime to invoke a MethodHandle linked to the specific `invokedynamic` bytecode. It is basically the implementation of `invokedynamic` that calls this adapter.

[Here is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/9d617cfd6717/src/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/Invokers.java#l380) the source where this adapter is generated.

Comment: Would that also work in case the class is not actually redefined? Meaning `redefineClasses`is called but no change in byte code is done. Or does such a call always result in the JVM clearing everything that was linked to those classes?

Comment: @HaasipSatang In my tests `redefineClasses` resets invokedynamic link even when called with the same bytecode. However, this behavior is not specified, and the real production applications should not rely on this.